# Alertview when there is no profile picture added (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Im new to programming and need some help here I have created a signup page in swift with some text fields and buttons for names, passwords. I have added a `UIImage` for users to add their picture. I want each users to MUST include a picture to be able to signup.

```
if (user does not include picture empty) <--- code here  {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "you need to       add profile picture", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

thank you.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this way if `imageView` is `nil` or not:

```
if yourImageView.image == nil {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "you need to add profile picture", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style:  UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```